# Why second button is not doing anything here?

Tags: javascript, dom

I got a todo app in JavaScript  which can add, delete entries against their functions. But once its clicks edit button only the first item is responding but other fails to do anything..

How to make it responsive and do the edit here.

Here is my code:

```js
// Define UI Vars
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.collection');
const clearBtn = document.querySelector('.clear-tasks');
const filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
const taskInput = document.querySelector('#task');
const editList = null;

// Load all event listeners
loadEventListeners();

// Load all event listeners
function loadEventListeners() {
  // Add task event
  form.addEventListener('submit', addTask);
  // Remove task event
  taskList.addEventListener('click', removeTask);

   //edit task
//
  // Clear task event
  clearBtn.addEventListener('click', clearTasks);
  // Filter tasks event
  filter.addEventListener('keyup', filterTasks);

}


// Add Task
function addTask(e) {
  if(taskInput.value === '') {
    alert('Add a task');
  }

  // Create li element
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  // Add class
  li.className = 'collection-item';
  // Create text node and append to li
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));
  // Create new link element
  const link = document.createElement('a');

  // Add class
  link.className = 'delete-item secondary-content';
  // Add icon html
  link.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i>';

  // Append the link to li
  li.appendChild(link);


  // Append li to ul
  taskList.appendChild(li);

  const editButton=document.createElement("button");//edit button
  editButton.className="editbtn";
  editButton.innerText="Edit";//innerText encodes special characters, HTML does not.
  li.appendChild(editButton);
  taskList.appendChild(editButton);
  const editList = document.querySelector('.editbtn');
  editList.addEventListener('click',editTask)

  // Clear input
  taskInput.value = '';

  e.preventDefault();
}

// Remove Task
function removeTask(e) {
  if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('delete-item')) {
    if(confirm('Are You Sure?')) {
      e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    }
  }
}

// Clear Tasks
function clearTasks() {
  // taskList.innerHTML = '';

  // Faster
  while(taskList.firstChild) {
    taskList.removeChild(taskList.firstChild);
  }

  // https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild
}


// Filter Tasks
function filterTasks(e) {
  const text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

  document.querySelectorAll('.collection-item').forEach(function(task){
    const item = task.firstChild.textContent;
    if(item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1){
      task.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      task.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}

function editTask (e) {
   console.log('clicked')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Task List</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div id="main" class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title">Task List</span>
            <div class="row">
              <form id="task-form">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="task" id="task">
                  <label for="task">New Task</label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Add Task" class="btn">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <h5 id="task-title">Tasks</h5>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <input type="text" name="filter" id="filter">
              <label for="filter">Filter Tasks</label>
            </div>
            <ul class="collection"></ul>
            <a href="#" class="clear-tasks btn black">Clear Tasks</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for reading my question

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because `const editList = document.querySelector('.editbtn');` is selecting the first button it finds and adds a click. It is NOT selecting the button you just added. So that first element is than firing that function multiple times since you keep adding more and more event listeners to it.

You already have the reference to the button, so there is no need to look it up.

```
editButton.addEventListener('click', editTask)
```

Comment: yes ,  you got it  right . why  its not  selecting  second button  from  `const editList = document.querySelector('.editbtn');`

Answer (score 0):

[`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first element matched.Every time you will call this `querySelector()` it will return the first edit button. Directly `addEventListener` to the `editButton` instead of calling it from `querySelector()`

```
 editButton.addEventListener('click',editTask)
```

Comment: @epascarello because he using `querySelector()` at many places. where he should have used `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: Because OP is adding it when a new button is added to the DOM. Making this change would add multiple click handlers to all the buttons. So each iteration, it would add another one.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry I didn't noticed that